# Software optimization guide for AArch64 Neon and SVE

Tags: arm, arm64, neon, sve

There is ARM software optimization guide (e.g., https://developer.arm.com/documentation/swog309707/latest for neoverse n1).

This guide doesn't seem to contain the latency and throughput for Neon or SVE. Is there a separate guide for NEON or SVE (e.g., the instruction latency and throughput for [`INSR (SIMD&FP scalar)` instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-12/SVE-Instructions/INSR--SIMD-FP-scalar---Insert-SIMD-FP-scalar-register-in-shifted-vector-?lang=en))?

A pointer would be very helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timings for Neon instructions *are* in that document, listed under ASIMD (which is Arm's more formal name for that instruction set).  See Sections 3.15 onward.

There are no timings for SVE instructions because, as I understand it, the N1 simply doesn't support that extension.  But if you look at the guide for some core that does support SVE, you'll see the timings included.  For the [Neoverse N2](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/PJDOC-466751330-18256/0000-03) they are from Section 3.26 onward.